# Django-datatable won't be added to INSTALLED_APPS

Tags: django, datatable

I have installed `django-datatable` and I want to add it to `INSTALLED_APPS` list.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'table',
)
```

Is `table` correct? If not, what should I type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at example/settings.py in the library:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    # ...
    'table',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    # 'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
)
```

Yes, just adding `table` is correct.

Comment: I did it. Thank you!